# How to hide graph view mode from a user in odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

I'm trying to hide the graph view mode from a user in `Odoo 10` but I didn't find any solution for that.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 steps:

- create a security group and user that you want show graph menu to this group
- make graph view only available in this category.

Comment: i'm proceeding with developping mode so i want to hide the record with the id purchase_order_graph. i tried to inherit it but i didtn't know how to give the manager privilègies to it knowing that the only group that i want it to see the graph view is group_purchase_manager. Do how know how to do that